# how to decide a nullable value type

Tags: c#, .net

```
void Main()
{

   test((int?)null);

   test((bool?)null);

   test((DateTime?)null);

}

void test(object p)

{

   //**How to get the type of parameter p**
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe this can help :

```
void Main()
{

   test<int>(null);

   test<bool>(null);

   test<DateTime>(null);

}

void test<T>(Nullable<T> p)
where T : struct, new()
{
   var typeOfT = typeof(T);

}
```

Comment: Dont forget `where T : struct`

Comment: @Magnus: followed your recommendation, and also adding the new() constraint (these constraints are actually the one defined on the [Nullable<T> type](http://http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/b3h38hb0.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

You cannot get the type because you didn't pass any value. There is no difference between the three invocations.

Casting a `null` value is only useful to make the compiler pick a specific overload of a function. Since you don't have an overloaded function here, the same function is called in all three cases. Without actually passing in a value, all your function will see is a `null` value, it cannot determine the type the caller cast that `null` value to.

Comment: Correct. A `null` value is not a instance of a class/struct and thus does not carry any type information.

Answer (score 1):

Every object in .NET has a `GetType()` method:

```
var type = p.GetType();
```

However, if you are trying to figure out the type of a parameter in this way, it is usually a sign that you're doing something wrong. You may want to look into overloaded methods or generics instead.

#### Edit

As an astute commenter pointed out, `null` has no type associated with it. For example:

```
((int?)null) is int?
```

The above expression will yield `false`. However, using generics, you can figure out what type the compiler expected the object to have:

```
void Test<T>(T p)
{
    Type type = typeof(T);
    ...
}
```

Again, I maintain that this sort of strategy is generally avoidable, and if you can explain why you need it, we can probably help you more.

Comment: Which will obviously throw an exception if p is null.. which is the case in dushouke's code

Comment: Cool, +1 now :) And I learned the word 'astute' that can be used as an alias for PITA :P

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the class name? That would get it:

```
  if(p != null)
  {
      p.GetType().FullName.ToString();
  }
```

Or only the type:

```
p.GetType();
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
If p IsNot nothing then
    GetType(p).GetGenericArguments()(0)
End If
```

(I assumed you were looking for the generic type, as getting the type of the object itself is quite simple)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to GetType, you can use the [is keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) like so:

```
void test(object p) {
    if (p is int?) {
        // p is an int?
        int? i = p as int?;
    }
    else if (p is bool?) {
        // p is an bool?
        bool? b = p as bool?;
    }
}
```

If p is null, then it could be `int?` or `bool?`, or any `object` or `Nullable` type.

One optimization is to use [as keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx) directly, like so:

```
void test(object p) {
    if (p == null)
        return; // Could be anything

    int? i = p as int?;
    if (i != null) {
        // p is an int?
        return;
    }

    bool? b = p as bool?;
    if (b != null) {
        // p is an bool?
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: As Christian has been pointing out to people, the point of this question appears to be to determine the type of something that is null. Neither `is` nor `as` will be useful in this case.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior - Yes, I say as much in my answer ;-)